# When does Redis pipelining become more efficient?

Tags: redis, pipeline, jedis

I was wondering, when does pipelining become more efficient? E.g. if I have to query the server once, a pipeline would be less efficient that just using the redis instance.

If I have to query the server twice, e.g. check something exists, if it does, grab it, is pipeline more efficient or is using the redis instance?

If I have to query something three times.. etc.

When does pipelining become more efficient than using the redis instance?~

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only operation once , it's the same .

The pipelining like batch process mechanism . If you have three commands to execute at the normal way , the client need send three tcp packets and receive three tcp packets (every command need send one and receive one ) ; but when use pipelining , the client package 3 command to server , just send one tcp packet and receive one .

You can see the official document : [Using pipelining to speedup Redis queries](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and is very helpful!

Comment: Hi, does it mean I should always use pipelining when there are more than 1 command to be sent to the server? Are there any disadvantages? I am asking this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900928 . You can have a look when you have time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sgon00 Yes , it has , because redis server is single thread to process command. If one client submit big pipelining  command , it will block other client to process . Just like mysql , you can query 10000 lines at once or query 100 line at  100 times .

Comment: @shaoyihe got that point. thanks a lot for your reply. so should I pipeline 10 SET commands? or should I simply send them one by one?

Comment: @sgon00 There's no single solution . I prefer pipeline 10 SET commands.