# Should I always use pipelining when there are more than 1 command in Redis?

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis, and a little bit confused when I should use pipelining or should I use it all the time when there are more than 1 command to be sent?

For example, if I want to send 10 SET commands to Redis server at a time, should I simply run the 10 commands one by one or should I pipeline them?

Are there any disadvantage to pipeline 10 SET commands instead of sending them one by one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when I should use pipelining

Pipeline is used to reduce RTT, so that you can improve the performance, when you need to send many commands to Redis.

> should I use it all the time when there are more than 1 command to be sent?

It depends. You should discuss it case by case.

> if I want to send 10 SET commands to redis server at a time, should I simply run the 10 commands one by one or should I pipeline them?

Pipline these commands will be much faster than sending 10 commands. However, in this particular case, the best choice is using the `MSET` command.

> Are there any disadvantage to pipeline 10 SET commands instead of sending them one by one?

With pipeline, Redis needs to consume more memory to hold the result of all these piped commands before sending them to client. So if you pipe too many commands, that's might be a problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the detail reply. One more question, what if I change 10 SET to 10 ZADD on 10 different keys? I think it's better just sending them one by one then. or maybe there are not much differences at all. Thanks.

Comment: There's no doubt that piping 10 ZADD commands should be much faster. If you DO care about the performance, pipeline might be a good choice. So why not do some benchmark to see whether is it worth pipelining these commands?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Please explain "the best choice is using the MSET command" -- I'm reading this trying to get a sense of where the crossover point is between pipelining SET calls and using MSET calls. In my case; I need to set 84K keys with around 1-2k of value for each. Blocking the servers' thread is an issue; so we currently chunk over the collection building payloads of ~1k k/v to give to MSET. Memory for 84k results is still tiny so not that concerned about that; but would pipelining allow the server to incrementally do the work or does it wait until the EXEC call to do all of the work and return?